# How to make multi-language app in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I have an application and I need to use two languages in that application.
For example :

- English
- Arabic

But I don't know how could I do that. Anybody can help me for this?

I need some examples in `C# Windows Forms`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Using `Localizable` and `Language` Property of Form**

`Form` class have `Localizable` and `Language` Property. If you set `Localizable` property to true, you can add controls to form for default language and set properties for default language. Then you can select another languages and change properties for those languages. This way, value or localizable properties will store in separate resource files for different cultures.

*Note: A property is considered as localizable if it's decorated with [`[Localizable(true)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.localizableattribute?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute. For example [`BackColor`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,5f9aebc2dd03f413) property is not localizable, but [`Text`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,952c66876790b53a) property is localizable.*

**Localizing Messages and Images using Resx Resource Files**

The project has a `Resources.Resx` file under `Properties` folder which you can use for localizing images and messages. Also you can add .resx Resource files to project. For example you can create a `Strings.resx` file and add some string key and values to it, then copy it as `strings.en.resx` and `strings.fa.resx` and edit values for those languages. Then you can use those resource values, For example:

```
MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.AreYouSure);
```

Will show the value of `AreYouSure` from `Resources.Resx` file with the current UI culture language.

If a resource key not found for a culture or the specified culture not found for the resource file, value of the key in neutral culture of the `Resx` file will be used.

**Change the language at Run-time**

You can set the culture of a application to `Persian` using:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa");

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa");
```

You should put the above code at start of your application or before showing a form.

**More information**

For more information and Example:

- [Globalizing Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/globalizing-windows-forms?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/y99d1cd3(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for Windows Forms Globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/b28bx3bh(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Answer (score 21):

Using a resource file might be easier in some cases.

1. Add a new resource file to the project in Visual Studio.
   eg. `en_local.resx`for english `fr_local.resx` for french.
2. Open the resource file, in the strings, name your string and put different translation in the value cell. For example: `next station`'s value in`en_local.resx` is `next station` but in `fr_local.resx` can be `Prochaine station`.
   example as below:
   [image: en_local.resx]
   [image: fr_local.resx]
3. In the code, use `public static ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("WindowsFormsApp1.en_local", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`
   to select the language resource.
4. When you need to output any string to the application, use function `GetString()`, for example             `label1.Text = rm.GetString("welcome");`

Comment: helpful....! It works ...

Answer (score 9):

There are some missing parts in wwjih123's answer.

In VS2017

1-First of all create resource in projects root folder (Not in Resources folder). Name it like lang_en, lang_tr, lang_fr etc...

2-then object properties window leave Build action as Embedded Resource

3-inside the lang_tr.resx file add new string lbl_error and value "Hata" in turkish (whatever you like)

4- inside the class define variables as:

```
    ResourceManager res_man;    // declare Resource manager to access to specific cultureinfo
```

5-in class initialization after InitializeComponent();

```
Console.WriteLine("You are speaking {0}", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
res_man = new ResourceManager("MyApp.lang_"+ System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

lblError.Text = res_man.GetString("lbl_error");
```

if your ui language is Turkish it will automatically load the lang_tr.resx,
if english the lang_en.resx file will be loaded
etc...

good luck

Comment: Why not in Resources folder??

Comment: I don't think the directory matters at all

Comment: Just want to point out that, for Chinese, one can use CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName to differentiate between traditional and simplified Chinese.

Answer (score -2):

Create an extension class and do as the following:

```
 public static class TranslateToKurdish
{
    public static void ToKurdish(this Control control,string kurdishText,float fontSize=10)
    {
        switch (control)
        {
            case TextBox textBox:
                textBox.PlaceholderText = kurdishText;
                textBox.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
                textBox.PlaceholderText = kurdishText;
                textBox.Font = new Font("Calibri", fontSize, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

                break;
            case Label label:
                label.Text = kurdishText;
                label.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
                label.Font = new Font("Calibri", fontSize, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

                break;
            case Button button:
                button.Text = kurdishText;
                button.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
                button.Font = new Font("Calibri", fontSize, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use in Form

```
   if (userLanguage == stringLanguage)
        {
            isKurdishLanguage = true;
            RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
            RightToLeftLayout = true;


            btnTruckTracking.Font = new Font("Calibri", 13.5F, FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));


            btnTruckTracking.ToKurdish(@"بارهه‌ڵگره‌كان",12);
            btnSearch.ToKurdish(@"گـــه‌ڕان",12);
            BtnProduct.ToKurdish(@"بـــه‌رهــه‌م",12);
            btnCompany.ToKurdish(@"كــۆمپـانیـایه‌كـان",12);
            btnUsers.ToKurdish(@"به‌كارهێنه‌ران",12);
            btnClose.ToKurdish(@"داخســـتن",12);

        }
```

Comment: this solution involves too many copy/paste code