# How to set two different Cultures for two different Controls on a single Form at the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, globalization, culture

I need to show an demo of how the control can be localized using the satellite assemblies. While doing this I have stuck with one place where i have two controls on a form both are same. I used to derive it from the Label. 
Now I need to display the `control1` with culture `fr-FR` and `control2` with the culture `de-DE`.

Is there any options is available to set different cultures for the same controls that displayed in a form.

The following screenshot will show my need.

[image]

Please suggest me is that possible or not. If its possible, let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on [localization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.71).aspx) feature of windows forms. This way you can setup your controls with different properties for different cultures. Then you can show the whole form with properties set for a specific culture.

Also you have option to show each control with a different culture. To do so it's enough to use such code in your form `Load` event handler:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
var resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(this.GetType());
resources.ApplyResources(button1, button1.Name);
```

And simply for `button2` use above code with `de-DE` culture.

**Note**

1. Above solution is not limited to `Text` property, it supports all `Localizable` properties.
2. You can simply make it as an extension method for control class.
3. It has designer-support for creating localized appearance of your controls.

Comment: For more information about multi-language applications using windows forms, see: [How to make multi language app in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32989100/3110834)

Comment: Is that the ApplyResources is only need to get the localized string from the resx file.

Comment: In a localized form, the `ApplyResources` will be automatically called in `InitializeComponent` for each control. What we did here is calling `ApplyResources` for a specific control after setting `CurrentUICulture` to a specific culture. This way can load different cultures for different controls if we need.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. it helps me to find the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Following code.

```
if(langCode=="fr-FR")
{
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
}
if(langCode=="de-DE")
{
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
}
```

Comment: where you are passing "langCode" value and their subsequent  Statement.

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to demonstrate localization feature for your application you can change current thread culture when you updating value for your control

```
private void SetLocalizedTextForLabel(Label label, string language)
{
    var original = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);

    // Here value will be retrieved from YourResource based on the current culture
    label.Text = Properties.YourResource.YourText;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = original;
}
```

Then use it

```
SetLocalizedTextForLabel(frenchLabel, "fr-FR");
SetLocalizedTextForLabel(germanLabel, "de-DE");
```

Comment: For demo this is okay. It is possible in a real work application. how can I provide support for these in a real application like, my control will have the default support for two different cultures on a same form in the core.