# C# WinForm Multi-Language with Resources

Tags: c#, winforms, multilingual

I have a problem. I got a project with several forms, I successfully added the multilanguage to my main form. (3 lang.) I made 3 buttons for the 3 languages, and on the button click event, the form language changes. But, if I click on the button to open the second form, the language don't change.

```
public void SrbBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Serbian language
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("sr-SP-Latn");
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load("Project");
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Project.Language.LangRes", a);
        podesiBtn.Text = rm.GetString("Podesi",ci);
        PomocBtn.Text = rm.GetString("Pomoc", ci);
        KonvertBtn.Text = rm.GetString("Konvert", ci);
        SacuvajBtn.Text = rm.GetString("Sacuvaj", ci);

        f2.label1.Text = rm.GetString("F2UNVB", ci);
        f2.label2.Text = rm.GetString("F2IzaberiValutu", ci);
        f2.ukCifraBtn.Text = rm.GetString("F2Dodaj", ci);
```

This is the form1 btnclick event. 
I have 1 res file for each language. How can I pass the language from one form to another? Shortly, When I perform the button click, the language must be the same on every form, not just only on the first.

Comment: [How to make multi language app in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32989100/3110834)

Comment: I saw this @RezaAghaei but this example you linked isn't built with the button_click combination. So it doesn't help me much :/

Comment: It seems you are not using `Localizable` property of `Form` and you are using your own method for localization, rather than the builtin method of Windos Forms.

Comment: Can you explain it to me please? Or can you tell me how I can use the Loc in this sintax?

Comment: I believe the linked answer and those links in the linked answer contain some useful description.