# Localization in winforms

Tags: winforms, localization

Resource files are not getting created for the newly added forms when the localized property is set to true in VS 2012.

When I add a new form to the project, set the Localizable property to true and build the application, .resx files are not getting created.

Comment: You should set both `Localizable` and `Language` properties. Probably you have not set `Language` property. ResX files are located under the `Form` node in solution explorer. Take a look at this post [How to make multi language app in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32989100/3110834).

Comment: i have set the language property and then built the application.Still resx file not getting created. And not only one , i have tried for Marathi , Telegu  and French. But none of the .resx file getting created.

Comment: I believe you have to modify a resource in the new language before it creates the ResX file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carefully follow [this walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.71).aspx). The experiment I did below in VS 2012 is working fine.

**Step1.**

Put a Label onto Form1

Set Form1.Localizable = true

Set Form1.Language = Default

Set label's text = "Hello world!"

[image]

**Step2.**

Set Form1.Language = Russian

Set label's text = "Привет мир!"

[image]

After these steps resource files become visible in Solution Explorer

[image]

Now add following code into Form1's constructor

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            switch (MessageBox.Show(
                "Press 'Yes' for default language, 'No' for Russian.",
                "Language Option", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
            {
                case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes:
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("");
                    break;
                case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No:
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru");
                    break;
            }
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Run the application and see the result.

The main purpose of the code is to show that CurrentUICulture must be set before the method InitializeComponent is called. In real applications, however, setting CurrentUICulture property, usually, takes place on program startup. So the code must be moved to where the program starts.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            switch (MessageBox.Show(
                   "Press 'Yes' for default language, 'No' for Russian.",
                   "Language Option", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
            {
                case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes:
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("");
                    break;
                case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No:
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru");
                    break;
            }
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

If you define UI language setting for your application then you can use the value of the setting here and set UI language. It will affect all forms you have defined in your application.