# LinkLabel.LinkArea localization issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization, linklabel

As you know LinkLabel control in WinForms supports selection of an area of text (stored in .resx) that will act as link by specifying start and position and length in LinkArea property. But localized text can and will change this exact values as in example below:

"Visit [our page](http://example.com) now!" [6, 7]

"Посетите [нашу страничку](http://example.com) сегодня!" [9, 13]

Is there a way to overcome this issue without using special characters and other messy workarounds?

Comment: [`LinkArea`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/LinkLabel.cs,be3deb0bd5eb942f) property is decorated with `Localizable` attribute and therefore it's localizable.

Answer (score 0):

[`LinkArea`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/LinkLabel.cs,be3deb0bd5eb942f) property is decorated with `Localizable` attribute and therefore it's localizable.

So if you set `Localizable` property of the `Form` to true, then you can set different value for localizable properties of controls for different languages. This way, property values will store in separate resource files for different cultures.

For more information and links to how to create multi-language windows forma application, take a look at:

- [How to make multi language app in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990088/3110834)

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem applying the solution or if you find it useful ...