# How set a culture for entire winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, culture, .net-4.6.2

I want to set a culture for entire winform application.
How can i do that?
I changed my `Program.cs` file like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Divar
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new RadForm1());
        }
    }
}
```

Did i do it right?

---

Also there is another link about that :(Please take a look)
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/set-cultureinfo-for-winform-application

This has limited success, so at the top of "Form1" before the InitializeComponent() I placed:

```
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
    Application.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
```

Is it necessary to add those three lines before the InitializeComponent() in every form?

Comment: yes you did it right, No it's not necessary.

Comment: Should i add this line > Application.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo; > to Main() method too?

Comment: Can u explain about those six lines about culture!

Comment: nothing to explain really. the names of the properties are self-explanatory. and to be sure you can set all four of them in `Main`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990088/3110834

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set these two in `Main` to the desired culture:
`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`
`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`

Additionally, you can change `Application.CurrentCulture` whenever you want to change the culture on the current thread of the application.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

    // this may fail sometimes: (see Drachenkatze's comment below)
    // var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    //Culture for any thread
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;

    //Culture for UI in any thread
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

    //Culture for current thread (STA)
    //no need for: Application.CurrentCulture = culture;

    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture == Application.CurrentCulture
    //no need for: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new RadForm1());
}
```

Comment: Note that `new CultureInfo("en-US");` did NOT retrieve the `CultureInfo` for `en-US` (.NET 4.7.2). The culture still had german decimal separators. I had to use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");` to make it work.