# Localize list view column headers via .resx Parent property

Tags: winforms, listview, localization, listviewitem

I need to localize listview columnheaders and trying to do it using .resx file in a winforms app. At the moment localization works only with controls (buttons, labels, ets.) which are located directly in the form. The Parent property for these controls is set to $this means they belong to the form.
But listview columnheaders located in a listview control. So I want to use the Parent property for columnheaders like in the following piece of code, but localization doesn't work.
How can I localize my listview?

```
<!--a label refers to the form-->
<data name="&gt;&gt;totalNumLbl.Parent" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>$this</value>
</data>
<!--I want to implement like:-->
<data name="&gt;&gt;materialsListView.Name" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>materialsListView</value>
</data>
<data name="materialName.Text" xml:space="preserve"> <!--columnheader-->
    <value>Mat Name</value>
</data>
<data name="materialName.Parent" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>materialsListView</value>
</data>
```

Comment: `ListView` supports localization properly. To learn how to setup localization take a look at this post: [How to make multi language app in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990088/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you