# How to display the datetimepicker in another language

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, cultureinfo

I can't get the datetimepicker text to show the abbreviation for the month in another language

I changed the regional settings for my PC to Dutch. That changes the month name from May to mei but I don't want to do that.

On start application:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-US", False)


ElseIf TypeOf a Is DateTimePicker Then
        If TableDataString(index) IsNot Nothing And TableDataString(index) <> "" Then
            Dim dt As Date = TableDataString(index).ToString
            TryCast(a, DateTimePicker).Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
            TryCast(a, DateTimePicker).CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
            TryCast(a, DateTimePicker).Text = dt
        Else
            Dim dt As Date
            TryCast(a, DateTimePicker).Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
            TryCast(a, DateTimePicker).CustomFormat = "  -  -  "
            TryCast(a, DateTimePicker).Text = dt
        End If
```

To change the date in a textbox I can do:

```
textbox.Text = result.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", New Globalization.CultureInfo("nl"))
```

This is not working

```
TryCast(a, DateTimePicker).Text = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", New Globalization.CultureInfo("nl"))
```

[image: datum]
[image: datum2]
I like May to show mei

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean, first you say `changes the month name from May to mei but I don't want to do that`. but then at the end you say `I like May to show mei` ? So I don't know what you want or don't want?

Comment: I don't want to change regional settings. I want to change it whatever the regional settings are.

Comment: [Globalizing Windows Forms applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/globalizing-windows-forms), [Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/y99d1cd3(v=vs.100)), simple instructions here [How to make multi language app in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990088/7444103).

Comment: I can set the form to Dutch with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("nl-NL") but that will mess up decimal numbers because we use a comma instead of a dot. I just want the datetimepicker changed not the whole form

Answer (score 0):

[As per the docs,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.text?view=netframework-4.8) the DateTimePicker class's `Text` property returns the text representation of the `Value` property based on the format of the `CustomFormat` property.

The `DateTime` object (in this case, the `Value` property) does not store culture information, and the default `ToString` method (that is called within the get function of the `Text` property) will attempt to use the `CurrentCulture` of the application. You will need to find a way to pass the `CultureInfo` object into the get function for the `Text` property of the `DateTimePicker` object.

That is the reason why setting the text with

```
TryCast(a, DateTimePicker).Text = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", New Globalization.CultureInfo("nl"))
```

does not work.

You could potentially inherit or extend from the `DateTimePicker` class to create your own custom implementation that stores and uses the `CultureInfo` to properly display the date.