# Attempted Localization Always Shows English on Windows Form App

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

I am trying to set up a Windows Form login screen that uses the user's language to set either German or English for a class. I have set up my `.resx` files within the Properties of my project, but I cannot figure out why the form always shows in English.

I reviewed [How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp) and [How to make multi language app in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989100/how-to-make-multi-language-app-in-winforms/32990088#32990088), which is where I found the information on setting up the `Strings.resx` and `Strings.de.resx` files, but the text when I set my UI Language to German always shows in English. On the LoginForm Properties, I have `Localizable` set to `True`.

As I want the app to load the screen with the correct language, I placed all my code in the Load Event:

```
        private void LoginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check system language 
            CultureInfo Language = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

            // Check if system language is set to German or English, and display
            // login screen elements as appropriate
            if (Language.Name.ToString() == "Deutsch")
            {
                LoginLabel.Text = Properties.Strings.LoginLabel;
                UserLabel.Text = Properties.Strings.UserLabel;
                PasswordLabel.Text = Properties.Strings.PasswordLabel;
                LoginButton.Text = Properties.Strings.LoginButton;
                ExitButton.Text = Properties.Strings.ExitButton;
            }
        }
```

I know I'm likely missing something simple, but I can't figure it out. If I need to, I can manually set the Text fields to the German version, but I'd rather have it separated in the `.resx` files if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `Language` to a `string`, and removed the `if` loop, and it's now appearing in German when set that way.