# How to get a value of a resource string from a resx file depending of the selected language?

Tags: c#, winforms, resx

I have two .resx file, `Form1.fr-FR.resx` and `Form1.en-US.resx`.
In this files, I add differents strings (same name for both .resx) and each string has a value depending on the .resx file.
Example

For `Form1.fr-FR.resx` :

```
Name | Value
string1 | bonjour
string2 | aurevoir
```

For `Form1.en-US.resx` :

```
Name | Value
string1 | hello
string2 | bye
```

I'd like that depending on the language selected, when I press a button, a texbox prints the value of the string1.
So if my form is in FR, it prints "bonjour", if it's in EN, it prints "hello".
If it can be minimalistic code that would be great

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989100/how-to-make-multi-language-app-in-winforms might help too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks for the link, this is working great

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
    textBox1.Text = rm.GetString("string1").ToString();
}
```