# Why do position and size of a button change when I change the language of the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, multilingual

I am developing an app on winforms which contains many controls. I want the application to be in multiple languages and the text of the buttons and labels change correctly. The problem is that in the first change of language I make (from default to spanish/english), the buttons and labels change their position and size, but I would like them to maintain as they were in the initial way. Do someone know why could this be?

This is the code I use:

```
private void English_ToolStrip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            English_ToolStrip.Checked = true;
            Spanish_ToolStrip.Checked = false;
            ChangeLanguage(typeof(Form1), "en");
        }

private void ChangeLanguage(Type t, string language)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(language);
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            { 
                resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(language));
            }
            foreach (ToolStripItem item in toolStrip1.Items)
            {
                if (item is ToolStripDropDownItem)
                    foreach (ToolStripItem dropDownItem in ((ToolStripDropDownItem)item).DropDownItems)
                    {
                        resources.ApplyResources(dropDownItem, dropDownItem.Name, new CultureInfo(language));
                    }
                resources.ApplyResources(item, item.Name, new CultureInfo(language));
            }
        }
```

I think I might be missing something when I initialize the form because the change of size and location only happens when I first change the language. After that, it doesn't matter to which language I change or how many times but the size and locations maintain the same.

[These are the controls before changing the language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjiQ2.png)

[These are the controls after changing the language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXtjs.png)

Comment: Check if there are multipe resource files (`form.en.resx` and `form.en-US.resx` are different ones). In winforms designer you can [change form language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990088/1997232) and that would load (and save) all data from a corresponding resource file. The control `Location` and `Size` may be different for each language.

Comment: Is it that the button text is actually bigger, and therefore requires more room?

Comment: @Sinatr I have three resource files: Form1.resx, Form1.en.resx and Form1.es.resx, they were generated automatically when I changed the texts for each language. I have looked and the Location and Size are the same for all the languages.

Comment: @Neil I have tried with different button texts and the size change happens always, even when the text is shorter.

Comment: Can you link to a picture that shows the change in size (before & after)?

Comment: @Neil I have just added the pictures in the description of the question.

Comment: I think here is something that is changing the font (or font size) in the new language. Could be some default in the resource file, or some other code doing it?

Comment: @Neil I haven't changed anything in the configuration of the controls, just the text. I'll look in the resource file if there is some change.

Comment: @Neil I have just tried to call the ChangeLanguage() function in the Load event of the form and the controls appear in the "big" way from the beginning, so, when I change the language again the size and position maintain the same. I will work with the form this way, so I do not need more answers. Thank you for all!! :)